# How can I click on a button which open in pop up window when cypress is not providing the suggested selector

Tags: cypress, ui-automation, browser-automation

For a website to login , login page open up in a pop up window.
email, and passwords are being entered successfully, but ' Sign In' button is not being captured neither cypress is suggesting any selector.
IF anyone knows please share

tried to used cy.window() and then cy.get('form').contains('Sign in').
But the problem is that pop up windows form does contains sign in text also other than that sign in button.

I have also tried this but problem is there is a sign in button on main page also which is opened in back ground.
cy.get('#join-neu-form > .wt-grid > .wt-grid__item-xs-12').as('Sign');
cy.find('button').contains('Sign in');

Comment: Can you provide the HTML of the website with the login popup present?

Comment: I think cy.origin() can be a solution for you. You need to replace the origin of your test with the link which triggers pop-up opening, then Cypress will see all locators on its popup and then revisit your original url. In order to prevent popup opening in a new window but in a tab use cy.stub() 
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin